# bibliography/citing error every other time, no in-text citations

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, journal-publishing, journal

To prepare submission for a journal, I am practically forced to use the **`sagej` documentclass**, available here: [SAGE](https://uk.sagepub.com/en-gb/eur/manuscript-submission-guidelines#LATEX). My MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass[PCfour,sageh,times,doublespace]{sagej}
% add doublespace for submitting for review
\usepackage{moreverb,url}

%\input{preambleOS}
\usepackage[colorlinks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,citecolor=red,urlcolor=red]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
cite like this: \cite{R1} and \citep{R2} and \citet{R2}

but why not like this like this: \cite{Fama1992} and \citep{Fama1992} and \citet{Fama1992}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem[Kopka and Daly(2003)]{R1}
Kopka~H and Daly~PW (2003) \textit{A Guide to \LaTeX}, 4th~edn.
Addison-Wesley.

\bibitem[Lamport(1994)]{R2}
Lamport~L (1994) \textit{\LaTeX: a Document Preparation System},
2nd~edn. Addison-Wesley.
\end{thebibliography}

\bibliography{mwebiblio}
\bibliographystyle{mslapa}

\end{document}
```

The style `mslapa` is suggested by the journal, and described as a very generic default style:

> "Please note that the ﬁles SageH.bst and SageV.bst are included with
>   the class ﬁle for those authors using BIBTEX. For APA style references
>   please use mslapa.bst which should be part of most modern TEX
>   distributions. See the above instructions regarding choos- ing the
>   correct reference option."

The bibliography file `mwebiblio` contains this (when opened in Texworks; I use Texworks and Miktex):

```
% Encoding: windows-1252

@Article{Fama1992,
  author  = {Eugene F. Fama and Kenneth R. French},
  title   = {The Cross-Section of Expected Stock Returns},
  journal = {The Journal of Finance},
  year    = {1992},
  volume  = {47},
  number  = {2},
  pages   = {427-465},
}

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:bibtex;}
```

When I compile, after having manually deleted all aux, bbl, and other files, it compiles (pdfLaTeX) great once, but **the second time, I receive the error**:

```
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   \def 
l.14 ...y not like this like this: \cite{Fama1992}
                                                   and \citep{Fama1992} and ...
```

From then on, the next compiling will go through without error, then this error again, etc.

However, the output is never satisfactory, because the in-text citations relating to the bib-file are always **only question marks:**

[image]

**What I need** is to include an external bibliography file (created with Jabref) with working in-text citations, as in the first sentence in the picture. (The only reason why I include the two entries manually and the bib-file at the same time here is to demonstrate the problem.)

---

**What I played with** is to replace `sageh` with `sageapa` in the class options, because I actually want to cite in APA style. But then I obtain the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.14 ...this like this: \cite{Fama1992} and \citep
                                                  {Fama1992} and \citet{Fama...
```

for seemingly every citing command that is not just plain `cite`. I noticed that the combination of `sageh` and `\bibliographystyle{mslapa}` is also in accordance with APA, so me having to use `sageh` like this is no further problem, but perhaps relevant to the first problem and its solution.

Comment: Where do your used class come from? https://uk.sagepub.com/sites/default/files/sage_latex_template_0.zip ?

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Comment: You seem to have both a manually generated `thebibliography` environment as well as one that's generated by BibTeX (stored in `\jobname.bbl`). Is this impression correct? If so, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mico, This was only to demonstrate the problem. The sample file comes with the manually added bibliography, but for practical reasons, I need to use Jabref, a bib-file, and the `\bibliography{}`-command

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the mslapa style then you must load the class with the `sageapa` option -- this will load the mslapa.sty instead of natbib (which is not compatible with the bst). You then can't use `\citep` and `\citet`:

```
\documentclass[PCfour,sageapa,times,doublespace]{sagej}
% add doublespace for submitting for review
\usepackage{moreverb,url}

%\input{preambleOS}
\usepackage[colorlinks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,citecolor=red,urlcolor=red]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

 but why not like this like this: \cite{Fama1992} and 


\bibliography{test}
\bibliographystyle{mslapa}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The above code works, but no longer when I also want to use in-text citations. Both `citet` and `citep` are then undefined commands.  However, I saw that in the specific journal that I want to submit to, in-text citations are very well acceptable, and I want to use them, too.

Comment: Check the documentation of mslapa. It describes the cite commands it offers http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/mslapa/mslapa.pdf.

Comment: Thank you. When I use the codes `\cite`, `\shortcite`, and  `\citeyear` in my otherwise unchanged MWE, I notice that `\citeyear` only gives gives as output "(1992)", unlike in the documentation (p.1-2, cases 1-3) where it suggests that `\citeyear` would give "Fama & French (1992)".  Can you help?

Comment: the example file uses something like "blah blah in the work of Dosher and colleagues \citeyear{DOSH89A}" to get a \citet-look. I don't see after a short look an easy way to write a real cite command for this as the parentheses are always added by the internal \@cite.

Comment: Thank you! I will then try to figure out how to define a citation that refers to author and year, but only puts the year in parentheses, because doing that manually is not an option for my work.